# Django Autoselect Foreign Key Value

Tags: django, forms

I have a model that contains a foreign key value, then in the form generated from this model, I want to auto select the record's key according to the record I'm adding the form's contents to...I've tried the below code, but it tells me QuerySet doesn't contain vehicle

```
stock = Issues.objects.filter(vehicle=id) 
form = IssuesForm(initial={'id_vehicle': stock.vehicle})
```

I'm a bit new to django btw so any ideas are highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` always gives a QuerySet, which is a set of values. If you just want a single object, you should use `get`.

However I don't really understand why you need to do the lookup at all. You have the `id` value already, since you are using it to look up `stock`. So why don't you just pass `id` as the value for `id_vehicle`?